# Prevent dropdown close click outside does work in codeply/jsfiddle but not within my own project?

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

Hello guy's i have a problem for day's i have been trying. But nothing works. I want the same effect as this -> https://www.codeply.com/go/Ai786lQzd8/bootstrap-4-prevent-dropdown-close-click-outside.

I want the dropdown menu only to close when i click on the button. I copied the EXACT code to my own project and it closes when clicking outside? It shouldn't close like the codeply example. I don't understand how to fix this.

I tried changing the code with a click target id and then let the dropdown menu close when ID is clicked but that also doesn't work i am out of options to try. I hope someone can help me with this.

**Here is my code**

```
    <li class='keep-open'>
    <a id='dropdownMenuLogin' class='nav-link badge no-style-for-badge' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Login</a>
        <!-- Dropdown login begins here -->
    <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-login mt-1'>
        <li class='p-3'>
            <form method='POST' id='loginFormHeader'>
                <!-- Login code should be here -->
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Here comes the jQuery code i tried it with:**

```
$('IF NOT -> #dropdownMenuLogin').click(function() {
    $('.keep-open').on({
        "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { this.closable = false; },
        "click":             function() { this.closable = false; },
        "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
  });
});
```

I want it closable false IF NOT clicked on `#dropdownMenuLogin`. So i want it only to close and open when i click on "the button" like codeply link in my case it is a `<a>` `#dropdownMenuLogin`

But the start of fixing this problem is why does it work in codeply and not in my own project i copied exactly everything to test it and it just closes when clicking on the outside.

**Jquery version: 3.4.1
Bootstrap version: 4.0.0**